# Derivative of inverse trig function with square root of another trig function inside.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I have to differentiate $\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\csc{x}})$ with respect to $x$. Used the inverse trig formula/identity to get $(\sqrt{\csc{x}})^2=\csc{x}.$

So then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\csc{x}}}$. This I multiplied by the derivative of the square root of $\csc{x}$ getting $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\csc{x}}}*-\frac{1}{2}*\csc{x}^{1/2}*\cot{x}$$

The answer given for the problem is saying $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\csc{x}}}*-\frac{1}{2}*\csc(x)*\cot x$$ though.

Comment: Common operators and standard functions often have their own $\TeX$-command, such as `\sin` and `\csc`. This is also explained in [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) basic MatJaX tutorial.

Comment: For me, your work is very correct. We can bet that, once more, typo's in a textbook ?

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I seem to run into that a fair bit in this course. It's not a book, it's all stuff the teacher has made up. Some time's I'm not quite sure if the mistake is with that or I'm just doing something stupid and not noticing when there's small differences between the answer and what I get like with this.

Comment: Since you asked the question, you cannot be stupid. So, how many hypotheses are left ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\csc(x)}\right)\right)=$$

---

Using the chain rule, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\csc(x)}\right)\right)=\frac{\text{d}\arcsin(u)}{\text{d}u}\cdot\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}$

where $u=\sqrt{\csc(x)}$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}u}\left(\arcsin(u)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$:

---

$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\csc(x)}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\csc(x)}}=$$

---

Using the chain rule, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{\csc(x)}\right)=\frac{\text{d}\sqrt{u}}{\text{d}u}\cdot\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}$

Where $u=\csc(x)$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}u}\left(\sqrt{u}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}$:

---

$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\csc(x)\right)}{2\sqrt{\csc(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\csc(x)}}=\frac{-\cot(x)\csc(x)}{2\sqrt{\csc(x)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\csc(x)}}=-\frac{\cos(x)\csc^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)}{2\sqrt{1-\csc(x)}}$$

Comment: You may want to look at the final result there again.